# Django + React , Google Login Button doesn't shown

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, google-api, react-google-login

I use frontend as React and backend as Django.

I want to add Google social login, but button doesn't shown.

I copy and paste this link,
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button

Here is my code.

react - index.html

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="1234567890-myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-login_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
  </div>
  <div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-size="large"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="sign_in_with"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
  </div>
```

django - urls.py
...
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'),),
...

error occured.

'/accounts' page works very well.

[GSI_LOGGER]: Error parsing configuration from HTML: Unsecured login_uri provided.

[image]

Comment: ??? React as frontend and Django as backend

Comment: Did you added javascript related to that button ?

Comment: I add it, but same issue occured.

Answer (score 0):

Change your *data-login_uri* to http://localhost:8000/...

*data-login_uri* does not accept non-HTTPS URIs, which are "Unsecure", the ONLY exception is "localhost" (for local development purposes), and "127.0.0.1" doesn't count.

Also, remember to add *both* http://localhost *and* http://localhost:8000 to *Authorized JavaScript origins*.